# Integral test for convergence?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Why does the series' terms have to be non-negative to use the integral test?

Consider the series:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{n\cos n - \sin n}{n^2}$$

Even though it has negative terms, why can't the integral test be used with the integral being:

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^2}$$

Since the series can be interpreted as the Riemann sum of the function above?

Comment: You need a monotonic function to be sure that you can estimate the partial sums. If the function oscillates, how are $f(n)$ and $\int_n^{n+1} f(t)\,dt$ related?

Comment: HInt: You need more than it being non-negative. It needs to be decreasing.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews But if it is just decreasing then the value of the integral is not equal to the sum or?

Comment: @DanielFischer But you *can* have monotonic series with negative terms can't you? (I know my example wasn't monotonic) If so, why would the terms *have* to be positive?

Comment: @dfg You can use the integral comparison test for a non-negative non-increasing function, or a non-positive non-decreasing function. These are symmetric, so one usually only mentions the non-negative case.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mjb4 Nobody said the integral is equal to the sum.

Comment: @thomasAndrews yeah I know! just wanted to make clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's precisely the fact that it has infinitely-many negative terms; the Integral Test only works when the sequence $a_n$ we're taking the series of is the restriction of a positive non-increasing integrable function $f(x)$.  To understand why, it is useful to understand the general idea of the proof of the integral test.  At this [site](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx) is a good illustration of the Riemann sums being taken and how they actually relate to the infinite series (this is one of the nice examples when the proof is essentially the picture).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a more general version of the Integral Test holds.

Let $f(x)$ be a monotone function for $x\ge x_0$. Then, the infinite series $\sum f(n)$ converges if and only if the improper integral $\int^\infty f(x)dx$ converges.

Answer (score -2):

Assume the following series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(\pi n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \pm 1$$ 
As you might know this series does not converge!

But if you look at the Riemann integral you have:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{1}^n \cos(x\pi)\text{d}x = 0 $$

Comment: The last equality is true, but that's not how the integral test works.

Comment: yeah but if your series is positiv and the integral is finite than the sum converges too or?

Comment: This would actually be an example where the conclusion of the integral test holds, although the hypotheses don't. Both the series from 1 to infinity and the integral from 1 to infinity of $\cos(\pi x)$ fail to exist.